# How to create privaterouter by extending Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I create PrivateRoute class that extends Route like this:

```
    class PrivateRouteContainer extends Route {

      render() {

        let component = super.render();
        let {user, path} = this.props;
        let match = this.state.match;
        if (match) {
          if (user.auth.isLogin) {
            return component;
          } else {
            return <Redirect to='/login' />;
          }
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      }
    };
```

And used it like

```
    <PrivateRouteContainer exact component={PanelContainer} path={ '/user' } />
    <PrivateRouteContainer component={OrderContainer} path={ '/user/order' } />
```

But i think i missed something because as the hash state changed, the rendered content still same and refresh the browser , it can get right content that from container rendered.

Need some helps to find out what i missed :)

Comment: what do you mean hash state

Comment: like 
http://domain/#/user  changed to 
http://domain/#/user/order

Comment: you will need to use specific router for hash handling, which is hashrouter https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter.

Comment: Yes, you're right. this's what i used. My issue is i used PrivateRoute that extends from Route class , and it  doesn't work anymore. but if change back to  Route directly, it works well again.

Comment: ok so lets take a look at a different angle, where does the `this.state.match` come from? or have you just mistaken if with `this.props.match` from router?

Comment: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/Route-props

Comment: i have found out the problem. Don't use connect() to wrapper PrivateRoute. Get the state from context .

Answer (score 0):

```js
class PrivateRouteContainer extends Route {

  render() {
    let {user, path} = this.props;
    let match = this.state.match;
    if (match) {
      if (user.auth.isLogin) {
        return super.render();
      } else {
        return <Redirect to='/login' />;
      }
    } else {
      return super.render();
    }
  }
};
```